# PHP Array Declaration With Class Definition

Tags: php, arrays, declaration

in my php code I get this error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: browserHeader in connectenparse.class.php on line 12
```

and my code start here with line 9

```
private $browserHeader = array ( "'0' => Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)");
    public function connectenParse($loginPage, $header=''){
        $this->loginPage = $loginPage;
        $this->browserHeader = $browserHeader[$header];
    }
```

My input is

```
$run = new connectenParse('http://example.com','0');
echo $run->streamParser();
```

streamParser function takes the variable end returns it. When I create the class with second parameter which is defined for browser header, it must return Mozilla/5.0. Where is the problem?

Comment: Are you going to `$this->browserHeader = $header;`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: @nerdlyist Now it returns '0', not the browser header

Comment: @u_mulder How did you see any possible dublicate between this question and the linked topic?

Comment: What returns 0? is `$header` in your function a string or an index?

Comment: $this->browserHeader returns 0

Comment: Answer the rest of my question please. Also what do you expect it to return.

Comment: @nerdlyist I expect it to return "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html"

Comment: There are a few issues with your code but I am not sure what you are even attempting to do so providing an answer is nearly impossible without some more clarification as to what you are doing.

Comment: If you can tell me the issues I can improve it. Thank you.

Comment: What are you inputs, what is you expected output and why is browserHeader and array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advise is that you do not need `$browserHeader` to be an array it is clearly a string and set it as needed.

```
private $browserHeader;
public function connectenParse($loginPage, $header=''){
    $this->loginPage = $loginPage;
    $this->browserHeader = $header;
}
```

Then you can call it like

```
$run = new connectenParse('http://example.com', "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)");
```

If you need the array for multiple other potential headers then you need to fix your array

```
const BROWSER_HEADER_LIST = array ("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)");
```

Notice it is not ("0=>...") that was making it part of the value. Also it is a const meaning you use it when needed.

So now you can do something like this

```
//Still have this variable
private $browserHeader;
//use numbers not strings for $header.
public function connectenParse($loginPage, $header=null){
    $this->loginPage = $loginPage;

    if($header !== null){
        $this->browserHeader = self::BROWSER_HEADER_LIST[$header];
    }
}
```

Also, connectenParse should probably be `__construct($loginPage, $header)` class name constructors are deprecated.

Comment: Best solution that I ever read. Thank you and thank you. You make my day :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are attempting to access the `$header` element of the `$browserHeader` array, without ever defining the `$browserHeader` array:

```
public function connectenParse($loginPage, $header=''){
    $this->loginPage = $loginPage;
    $this->browserHeader = $browserHeader[$header];
}
```

On the third line you are assigning a value to `$this->browserHeader`, which is perfectly fine, but the value you are assigning is `$browserHeader[$header]`. `$header` exists, however this method is unaware of any variable called `$browserHeader`, which is why you're seeing the error. You probable mean to do the following instead:

`$this->browserHeader = $header;`

Comment: It returns '0', I have to take  Mozilla/5.0 header. When I create the class with second parameter which is defined for browser header, it must return Mozilla/5.0

Answer (score 0):

Your `$browerheader` variable should be like this

```
private $browserHeader = array ("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html");
```

If you are passing `$header` value to a function call, you should use

```
$this->browserHeader = isset($this->$browserHeader[$header]) ? $this->$browserHeader[$header] : $this->$browserHeader[0];
```

If `$header` is a string, you can use it like this

```
$this->$browserHeader = $header;
```